# Enable Radio button On page Load angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px;" ng-repeat="row in skuDetails">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="amount_{{$index}}" value="amount" ng-model="row.amount" ng-checked="row.reductionAmount != '' ">Reduction Amount
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <input type="text" name="reductiontext" value="" ng-model="row.reductionAmount" style="width: 80px;">
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <input type="radio" name="percentage_{{$index}}" value="percentage" ng-model="row.amount">Reduction Percentage
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <input type="text" name="reductiontext" value="" ng-model="row.reductionPercentage" style="width: 80px;">
  </label>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
dao.getPromotion(scope.sesssionMessageObject.promotionId).then(function(response) {
  scope.responseObject = response.data.data;
  console.log(scope.responseObject);
  scope.skuDetails = scope.responseObject.skus;
});
```

Hi.I am having a problem in enabling a radio button on page Load.Problem is , When my page is loaded an api is called from controller and data is stored in skuDetails(contains name , mrp reductionAmount etc). In view i will loop through skuDetails and enable radio button Reductionamount if reductionAmount(integer)  contains value. getPromotion calls api and retrieve details.But not working!

Comment: do you want that the radiobutton to be checked or enabled?

Comment: do not treat `reductionAmount` as a string. An interger cannot be empty

Comment: @SankarRaj I need the radiobutton to be checked

Comment: @AvantikaSaini the user might or not enter the value while giving inputs

Comment: Show your full code.

Comment: Share your code for the controller

Comment: @Avantika Saini added

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(scope.responseObject)`

Comment: @AvantikaSaini it prints values of barcode mrp name ect.And reductionAmount contaons 12

Comment: Try displaying `{{row.reductionAmount}}` in your view. I think that your object is not formed properly

Comment: It printed as 12. Already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-init` like following

```
<div ng-repeat="row in skuDetails" 
     ng-init="row.amount = row.reductionAmount != '' ? true : false">
```

And Remove this `ng-value="row.reductionAmount != ''` I don't think it is making any sense here

Comment: Did you try it ? you can try using a controller function with above script

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<input ng-init="(!!row.reductionAmount)?row.amount = row.reductionAmount:''" type="radio" name="amount_{{$index}}" value="{{row.reductionAmount}}" ng-model="row.amount">Reduction Amount
```

Checkbox will be checked only if the `value` and value in your ng-model are same.

So we are doing this,

```
row.reductionAmount -------> value attribute
row.reductionAmount -------> row.amount (only when row.reductionAmount is not null)
```

we are assigning `row.reductionAmount` to `row.amount` and setting `value` attribute to `row.reductionAmount`

Comment: @AnushaBayya Do you want it be checked or disabled?

Comment: I need it to be checked if row.reductionAmount contains value.uncheck if it doesnot contain

Comment: @AnushaBayya I have updated the answer please try now.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with `ng-value` instead of `ng-checked` and also remove `value` attribute, i think it is meaningless.

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px;" ng-repeat="row in skuDetails">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="amount_{{$index}}" ng-model="row.amount" ng-value="row.reductionAmount != ''">Reduction Amount
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <input type="text" name="reductiontext" value="" ng-model="row.reductionAmount" style="width: 80px;">
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <input type="radio" name="percentage_{{$index}}" value="percentage" ng-model="row.amount">Reduction Percentage
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <input type="text" name="reductiontext" value="" ng-model="row.reductionPercentage" style="width: 80px;">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Then you might check your data

Comment: I printed the value too and checked.It contains 12

Comment: what is the type of `row.reductionAmount`?

Comment: type of row.reduction amount is int

Comment: how about replace 0 with '' ?